# Сортировка данных ORDER BY

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Как сохранить отсортированный результат в новую таблицу?

```
INSERT INTO out_DB(id, A) VALUES ('6', '63')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#out_1](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[A] [varchar](200) NULL,
[B] [varchar](8000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO #out_1 SELECT id, A, B FROM out_DB ORDER BY id 

SELECT * INTO out_result FROM #out_1
```

Comment: Просто сделайте id кластерным первичным ключом. Тогда вам одной таблицы хватит, хотя смысл ваших намерений от меня ускользает.

Comment: В таблице порядка записей НЕТ. даже отсортированный набор, будучи помещённым в таблицу, превращается в кучу. Нужен порядок - сортируйте в запросе.

Comment: @msi, даже кластеризованный индекс не гарантирует вывод без ORDER BY в том же порядке. Об этом прямо написано в документации.